# cxf wsdl2java error failed to generated types

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

I try to use wsdl2java from the apache cxf 3.1.4, but received the follow error: failed to generated types, and i have the wsdl in the same folder which is the C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-cxf-3.1.4\bin. So what i have to do to wsdl generate a java, and the wsdl file follows below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://www.andre.dionisio.nom.br/SOAPWS/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="SOAPWS" targetNamespace="http://www.andre.dionisio.nom.br/SOAPWS/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.andre.dionisio.nom.br/SOAPWS/">
      <xsd:element name="GetAverageEmployeesSalary">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="in" type="xsd:string"/>
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="GetAverageEmployeesSalaryResponse">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="out" type="xsd:string"/>
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="CalculateEmployeeBonus">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>

                <xsd:element name="in" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
    </xsd:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="GetAverageEmployeesSalaryRequest">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:GetAverageEmployeesSalary" name="parameters"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetAverageEmployeesSalaryResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" type="xsd:decimal" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="CalculateEmployeeBonusRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="employeeId" type="xsd:long"></wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="CalculateEmployeeBonusResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="bonus" type="xsd:decimal"></wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetAverageEmployeesSalaryRequest1">

        <wsdl:part name="empty" type="xsd:string"></wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="SOAPWS">
    <wsdl:operation name="GetAverageEmployeesSalary">

            <wsdl:input
                message="tns:GetAverageEmployeesSalaryRequest1">
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:GetAverageEmployeesSalaryResponse" name="parameters"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="CalculateEmployeeBonus">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:CalculateEmployeeBonusRequest" name="employeeId"></wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output message="tns:CalculateEmployeeBonusResponse" name="bonus"></wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="SOAPWSSOAP" type="tns:SOAPWS">
    <soap:binding style="document"
        transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="GetAverageEmployeesSalary">
        <soap:operation
            soapAction="http://www.andre.dionisio.nom.br/SOAPWS/GetAverageEmployeesSalary" />
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="parameters">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="CalculateEmployeeBonus">
        <soap:operation
            soapAction="http://www.andre.dionisio.nom.br/SOAPWS/CalculateEmployeeBonus" />
        <wsdl:input name="employeeId">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="bonus">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="SOAPWS">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:SOAPWSSOAP" name="SOAPWSSOAP">
      <soap:address location="http://www.andre.dionisio.nom.br/"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: Please share the command you use for running `wsdl2java`. Having the installation under `Program Files` might be problematic because of the white space in the path. I normally install these utilities under `C:/apps/` (or similar) for this reason.

Comment: Solve, i put in another machine in a path without spaces in the name and run in a old java 1.7.0_55-b13 java_home for both wsdl. The command was wsdl2java SOAPWS.wsdl and for the other file i put a name old so the command is wsdl2java SOAPWSold.wsdl.

Comment: Putting the executable in a path without spaces solved my problems too.